# Elasticsearch aggregation query not able to present any result

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, aggregate

I was wondering what had happened to my Elasticsearch index that I am not able to apply any aggregation query. I am able to send a simple search query, and the cluster status is also green, but aggregation queries return zero results!

Sample query:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' {    "size" : 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "severity" : {
            "terms" : {
              "field" : "severity"
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

Elasticsearch index:

```
"severity":
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    }
```

P.S: I cannot see any error or any suspicious part in the log files.

Comment: And your documents all have values in the `severity` field?

Comment: @Val Yes, they all have some values for the "severity" field. Also, I am able to search on "severity" for a specific value.

Comment: Very strange... can you show a sample document and also what you get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index` ?